# Owncloud very slow on file rescanning

Tags: owncloud

I'm running an owncloud server and I've needed to install it from scratch and copy the files from a backup.

When I try to update the files with occ: `sudo -u www-data php occ files:scan --all` tt takes no less than 0.5 seconds per file. I have about 80k files, so it will take a lot.

Is it normal? Is there a way to speed up the process?